# General expression for the pdf of the sum of k-th ordered statistics

Tags: order-statistics

I have M samples, each sample containing N random variables drawn independently from the same distribution. I am interested in computing the PDF of the sum of the M k-th ordered statistics associated with each sample. Is there a general expression for this PDF when the random variables are drawn from an exponential distribution?

Comment: Are you asking for the PDF of the sampling distribution of the statistic? Can you provide a short concrete example?

Comment: The probability density function for the $k$th order statistic of a sample of size $n$ from a distribution with pdf $f(x)$ and distribution function $F(x)$ is

$$f_k(x) = n {n-1\choose k-1} F(x)^{k-1} (1-F(x))^{n-k} f(x)$$

and, since the exponential distribution with mean 1 has pdf $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and distribution function $F(x)=1-e^{-x}$, we can compute

$$f_k(x) = n {n-1\choose k-1} (1-e^{-x})^{k-1} e^{-(n-k+1)x}$$

Is there a general expression for the sum of M random variables drawn from the above distribution ?